# Non-idle alternative to QTimer for periodically called function

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling

I have a simple 3D rendering framework inside a widget with an `update()` method responsible for rendering each frame. At the moment I'm using a `QTimer` to trigger an update 60 times per second, which seems to work ok:

```
void RenderingWidget::init()
{
    // ...

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(16);
}
```

The problem with this solution is that there is possibly 16 ms of idle time in between the frames regardless of how fast they are rendered. In a native Windows application I could implement my own message loop and keep rendering frames continuously if there are no other events to process. Is there something similar I could do in Qt?

Here's something I thought about, which also appears to work ok, however I've read that it may be a bad practice (i.e. using `QApplication::processEvents()`):

```
void RenderingWidget::run()
{
    running = true;

   while(running)
   {
        update();
        QApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `QApplication::processEvents` is OK in your case. You can also implement rendering in `paintEvent` function of your widget and invoke it immediately using `repaint()`. You can limit frame rate manually using `QElapsedTimer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured it out! While there is no direct access to the message loop in Qt, there is a `QObject::event()` method which acts similarly to `WndProc()` in Windows API.

A way to achieve what is mentioned in the question is to reimplement this method by subclassing a `QWidget` or the `QApplication` and then handling a `QEvent::UpdateRequest` event by calling the `update()` method or, in any other case, passing the event to the base class where the default handler will deal with it (similarly to default windows procedure in win api). After doing the update you add another update request to the queue and, unless there are other events in between, the control goes back to `update()` and so on.

Here's an example implementation:

```
class RenderingWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RenderingWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~RenderingWidget();

public slots:   
    void update() 
    { 
        // do all rendering work
        updateLater();    // queue another update
    }

    void updateLater()
    {
        if (!m_updatePending)
        {
            m_updatePending = true;
            QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest);
        }
    }

protected:        
    bool m_updatePending;    

    bool event(QEvent* event)
    { 
        if (event == QEvent::UpdateRequest)
        {
            m_updagePending = false;
            update();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return QWidget::event(event);
        }
    }
};
```